# Redshift - how to replace multiple values in string with result of listagg

Tags: replace, amazon-redshift

I have a table called 'packages' that looks like this:

```
| id | route            | arrival_datetime       | node | type  | 
| -- | ---------------- | ---------------------- | ---- | ----- | 
| 2  | 1->4->A->3->B->2 | 2023-01-01 08:00:00+00 | A    | type1 | 
| 2  | 1->4->A->3->B->2 | 2023-01-01 10:00:00+00 | B    | type2 | 
| 1  | 1->4->A->B->2    | 2023-01-01 08:00:00+00 | A    | type1 | 
| 1  | 1->4->A->B->2    | 2023-01-01 09:00:00+00 | B    | type2 |
```

In it, we have packages.

- each package has an ID
- each package goes through multiple sites (nodes)
- site names in the route can either be letters (any letter) or numbers (any number).
- the route can contain an undefined number of letter nodes
- the table primary key is ID + node
- the table only contains packages that go through sites that are letters
- field arrival_datetime says when a package arrives in a node
- to each pkey is associated a different value of 'type' field

Problem statement:

I want to add a new column called "route_replaced".
The column needs to contain: the same route present in the group with same ID, replacing each node that is a letter with the corresponding type

```
| id | route            | arrival_datetime       | node | type  | route_replaced|
| -- | ---------------- | ---------------------- | ---- | ----- | ------------ |
| 2  | 1->4->A->3->B->2 | 2023-01-01 08:00:00+00 | A    | type1 | 1->4->type1->3->type2->2 |
| 2  | 1->4->A->3->B->2 | 2023-01-01 10:00:00+00 | B    | type2 | 1->4->type1->3->type2->2 |
| 1  | 1->4->A->B->2    | 2023-01-01 08:00:00+00 | A    | type1 | 1->4->type1->type2->2 |
| 1  | 1->4->A->B->2    | 2023-01-01 09:00:00+00 | B    | type2 | 1->4->type1->type2->2 |
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

So far I am thinking of something like this

```
select *,
LISTAGG(node || '_' || type, '->') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY arrival_datetime asc) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
from packages
```

which returns:

```
| id | route            | arrival datetime       | node | type  | listagg      |
| -- | ---------------- | ---------------------- | ---- | ----- | ------------ |
| 2  | 1->4->A->3->B->2 | 2023-01-01 08:00:00+00 | A    | type1 | A_type1->B_type2 |
| 2  | 1->4->A->3->B->2 | 2023-01-01 10:00:00+00 | B    | type2 | A_type1->B_type2 |
| 1  | 1->4->A->B->2    | 2023-01-01 08:00:00+00 | A    | type1 | A_type1->B_type2 |
| 1  | 1->4->A->B->2    | 2023-01-01 09:00:00+00 | B    | type2 | A_type1->B_type2 |
```

But then from here I am not sure how to replace the values returned by listagg into the route value..